# Missing or invalid module: Kint in update.php

Tags: 9

I have updated my project to Drupal 9.4.1 from Drupal 8 and updated all packages with the composer successfully.
But when I want to run the update.php file then the error popped up. It says "Missing or invalid module The following module is marked as installed in the core.extension configuration, but it is missing: **kint**".

I have installed "**drupal/devel**": "**4.0**" in my project.

My core.extension.yml file is empty.
module: {}
theme: {}
profile: ''

So, what should I do to remove the error? Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: See the release notes of devel 4.0: https://www.drupal.org/project/devel/releases/4.0.1

Comment: `composer require drupal/devel_kint_extras` will get you both.

Comment: Looks like you should have uninstalled both `devel` and `kint` before the upgrade.